# MySQL Query - Adding up columns & rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I currently have two tables, one is products and the other is options (colour, size, etc).
If no options are specified for the product, it puts the stock against the product table
Otherwise it will put the stock against the option table

Tables look a bit like this:

**Product table:**
productid, name, sku, stock

**Option table:**
optionid, productid, sku, stock

I want to pull the data from both tables, and add up the "stock"

**So far I have this:**

```
SELECT `product`.`productid`, `product`.`name`, `product`.`sku`,

( SUM(`product`.`stock`) ) + ( SUM(`option`.`stock`) ) AS `stock`

FROM `product`

LEFT JOIN `option` ON `product`.`productid` = `option`.`productid`

GROUP BY `productid`
```

Which displays the data how I want but the issue is with the stock.
For a product that has options specified, it adds them up nicely.
If the product doesn't have an option, it just displays "NULL"

Results [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `product`.`productid`, `product`.`name`, `product`.`sku`,

IFNULL(SUM(`product`.`stock`),0) + IFNULL(SUM(`option`.`stock`),0) AS `stock`

FROM `product`

LEFT JOIN `option` ON `product`.`productid` = `option`.`productid`

GROUP BY `productid`
```

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the NULL problem, you need to wrap the SUM in a COALESCE.

```
 SUM(`product`.`stock`) + COALESCE(SUM(`option`.`stock`), 0) AS `stock`
```

This is because `SUM(NULL)` yields `NULL`, and `x + NULL` = `NULL`.  Using COALESCE changes the `NULL` into a `0`, giving `x + 0` which equals `x`.

I can also see a potential issue.

If one product can have many options, the LEFT JOIN will cause duplication in the product records, artificially inflating your stock count.

For example...

```
product id   stock  |  option id   stock
    1          5           1         1
    1          5           2         2
    2          7           3         1
    2          7           4         2
    2          7           5         3
```

Although the stock for product 1 is 5, the join makes it look like 10.  and for product 2, which has 7 stock, it looks like 21.

The solution is to GROUP BY for the options separately.

```
SELECT
  `product`.`productid`,
  `product`.`name`,
  `product`.`sku`,
  `product`.`stock` + COALESCE(`option`.`stock`, 0)  AS `stock`
FROM
  `product`
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT `productid`, SUM(`stock`) AS stock FROM `option` GROUP BY `productid`) as `option`
    ON `option`.`productid` = `product`.`productid`
```

Comment: I replicated what you said, and the accepted answer didn't duplicate the stock levels. As soon as a option is specified against a product, the stock on the product gets set to zero and gets disabled. So this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement:

```
SELECT `product`.`productid`, `product`.`name`, `product`.`sku`,

IF(`option`.`stock`, SUM(`option`.`stock`), SUM(`product`.`stock`) ) AS `stock`

FROM `product`

LEFT JOIN `option` ON `product`.`productid` = `option`.`productid`

GROUP BY `productid`
```

I've put IF condition in the select.
Edited ! To sum option.stock if available

Comment: It seems to ignore adding up my stock off the options table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `product`.`productid`, `product`.`name`, `product`.`sku`,

( SUM(`product`.`stock`) ) + ( CASE WHEN `option`.`stock` = NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(`option`.`stock`) ) AS `stock`

FROM `product`

LEFT JOIN `option` ON `product`.`productid` = `option`.`productid`

GROUP BY `productid`
```

The problem is that when you try to add `NULL` the result is `NULL`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EKSE SUM(`option`.`stock`) ) AS `stock` FROM `product` LEFT JOIN `option` ON `' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
select `productid`, `name`, `sku`, sum(`stock`) `stock`
from (select `productid`, `name`, `sku`, `stock` FROM `product`
      union all
      select `productid`, '' `name`, '' `sku`, `stock` FROM `option`) v
GROUP BY `productid`
```